# How to call C++ DLL function from VB?

Tags: c++, wpf, vb.net, dllexport

I need to call a function from C++ Dll (BVRelate.dll) through Visual Basic (VBWpf).

C++ dll code:

```
//VBRelate.h

#ifdef VBRELATE_EXPORTS
#define VBRELATE_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define VBRELATE_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern VBRELATE_API void DoSomething();

//VBRelate.cpp

#include <atlstr.h>
#include "VBRelate.h"

VBRELATE_API void DoSomething()
{
    CString strOutput("Hello world");
    MessageBox(NULL, strOutput, L"Got a message", MB_OK);
}
```

Then I try to call this function from VB (wpf project)

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Class MainWindow
    Declare Function DoSomething Lib "M:\VBRelate.dll" ()
    Private Sub button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles button.Click
        DoSomething()
    End Sub
End Class
```

And I got an exception:

"MarshalDirectiveException was unhandled". An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException' occurred in VBWpf.exe

Then I used dumpbin:

```
dumpbin /exports "M:\VBRelate.dll">M:\VBRelate.txt
```

and in VBRelate.txt was this:

```
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file M:\VBRelate.dll

File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for VBRelate.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    57E3DDA6 time date stamp Thu Sep 22 16:33:26 2016
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           1 number of functions
           1 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 00011299 ?DoSomething@@YAXXZ = @ILT+660(?DoSomething@@YAXXZ)

  Summary

        1000 .00cfg
        4000 .data
        1000 .gfids
        1000 .idata
        4000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
       10000 .text
       10000 .textbss
        1000 .tls
```

Then I was trying to use def file, but not really fully understand how to use it (where should it be - with dll file, with project files or somewhere else) and why should I use it while using __declspec (not __stdcall). So I put the def file in the directory with dll file, and also with dll projects files:

```
; VBRelate.def - defines the exports for VBRelate.dll

LIBRARY VBRelate.dll
DESCRIPTION 'A C++ dll that can be called from VB'

EXPORTS
    DoSomething
```

Then I rebuilt dll.
It didn't work. The same exception appeared. And dumpbin returned the same dump, nothing was changed.

Comment: Program with Option Strict On for a while so the compiler can tell you about a simple mistake like this.  It is a Sub, not a Function.

Comment: I switched on this option, thanx. I tried Declare Function DoSomething Lib "M:\VBRelate.dll" () As Object and also Declare Sub DoSomething Lib "M:\VBRelate.dll" (). The same problem

Comment: Adding extern "C" in dll function declaration and definition made it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**

Adding extern "C" in dll function declaration and definition made it work.

```
 //VBRelate.h
 #ifdef VBRELATE_EXPORTS
 #define VBRELATE_API __declspec(dllexport)
 #else
 #define VBRELATE_API __declspec(dllimport)
 #endif

extern "C" VBRELATE_API void DoSomething();

//VBRelate.cpp
extern "C"
{
    VBRELATE_API void DoSomething()
    {
        CString strOutput("Hello world");
        MessageBox(NULL, strOutput, L"Got a message", MB_OK);
    }
}
```

so as I think the problem was in decorated name. After adding extern "C" the dump file looked like this:

```
Microsoft (R) COFF/PE Dumper Version 10.00.40219.01
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.


Dump of file M:\VBRelate.dll

File Type: DLL

  Section contains the following exports for VBRelate.dll

    00000000 characteristics
    57E52794 time date stamp Fri Sep 23 16:01:08 2016
        0.00 version
           1 ordinal base
           1 number of functions
           1 number of names

    ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 000112C1 DoSomething = @ILT+700(_DoSomething)

  Summary

        1000 .00cfg
        4000 .data
        1000 .gfids
        1000 .idata
        4000 .rdata
        1000 .reloc
        1000 .rsrc
       10000 .text
       10000 .textbss
        1000 .tls
```

So the function name now is right, but it was ?DoSomething@@YAXXZ

Answer (score 0):

The problem does not appear to be within the DLL/native C++ code, although maybe if you made it a managed C++ dll? The exception is saying there is something wrong with handling the data between managed (VB) and unmanaged (C++) code: [MarshalDirectiveException on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshaldirectiveexception(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

It may be possible to change the attributes using `MarshalAsAttribute()` [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshalasattribute(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Don't understend... which attributes should I marshal? The function is void type and has no arguments... void DoSomething()

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with function name? As I read it should be not like this ?DoSomething@@YAXXZ = @ILT+660(?DoSomething@@YAXXZ) in dump

Comment: Adding extern "C" in dll function declaration and definition made it work.